# How can I cancel a single touch event that is in progress in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a game where the user is dragging an object. I want to stop moving the object when an event happens while the user is still trying to drag the object. Is there a way to do this? Basically cancel a touch that is currently in progress while not impacting other touch events that may be happening since this is a multi-touch application.

I'm using cocos2d v1.1.0 and am using ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesMoved.

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the following codes where you want to cancel the touch events.

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:NO];
```

Or the deprecated method

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do it with a flag on the dragged object?

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan...
{
      touchedObject.canDrag = YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved...
{
      if (touchedObject.canDrag)
      {
           //Drag
      }
}

- (void)eventThatStopsDrag
{
      touchedObject.canDrag = NO;
}
```

Comment: Ben thanks for the suggestion. I don't know if it's my particular nature, but that feels like a patched solution since I'd like to also take action once the drag stops too. With your suggestion, I'd need to add another property to set for that action when it seems like I should just be able to cancel the touch. Don't get me wrong, in absence of anything else, I'm gonna have to do what you suggested and had come up with the same patch while waiting for responses. So thanks for the pointer, in the end it might be all we've got but I'm hoping there is some cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocos2dx-js then you can write this code in you main.js

When ever your mouse cursor goes outside the window it will dispatch mouseup event.
Its most helpful while considering the scenario, you are dragging any sprite and you want to cancel the mousemove event when cursor goes out of window.

```
cc.game.onStart = function{


    .......................

    .......................

    .......................


    var prohibition = false;
    if( cc.sys.isMobile)
        prohibition = true;
    var selfPointer = cc.inputManager;
    var element = cc._canvas;
    element.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
        if(prohibition) return;
        selfPointer._mousePressed = false;

        var pos = selfPointer.getHTMLElementPosition(element);
        var location = selfPointer.getPointByEvent(event, pos);

        selfPointer.handleTouchesEnd([selfPointer.getTouchByXY(location.x, location.y, pos)]);

        var mouseEvent = selfPointer.getMouseEvent(location,pos,cc.EventMouse.UP);
        mouseEvent.setButton(event.button);
        cc.eventManager.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });


    .......................

    .......................

    .......................


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (not checked code):

```cpp
void onTouchMoved(Touch* touch, Event* event) {
    ...
    if (needCancel) {
        EventTouch cancelEvent;
        cancelEvent.setTouches({touch});
        cancelEvent.setEventCode(EventTouch::EventCode::CANCELLED);
        Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->dispatchEvent(&cancelEvent);
    }
}
```

but touch is still present and events will come